# Background-color shows through an SVG icon with the exact same size

Tags: css, mobile, svg, rendering

At first let me aknowledge you to this issue. I had an anchor with these properties:

`.upvote_box a {
    width: 20px;
    height: 21px;
    display:block;
    background-color: #828282;
    background-image: url(../imgs/upvote.svg);
    background-size: 20px 21px;
}`

The `background-color` there has a meaning, because it transits into a different color through CSS3 transitions. So my SVG is a white box with a cut hand icon in it. The rendering on Chrome on desktop was fine. But then I checked Safari and I saw these tiny lines around this anchor. So then I made an SVG icon with `1px border` in it. So the dimensions of the SVG after that were `width: 22px; height:23px;`Of course I changed all the setting in the CSS, too. But I also added one thing to prevent this from happening – `box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff`  – this solved the problem in Safari on desktop. But the problem sustains on mobile Chrome and mobile Safari.

This is what it looks like:

[image: visible borders around the anchor]

Also there is link to JSFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Teglik11/gU5cH/2/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this :

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

or this :

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff
```

Comment: I tried your first option – didn't help. Also I've already tried the second one by my own before, it's even in my question.

Comment: use together.i hope help you.
did you using -webkit befor box shodow?